# Alfresco getChildren Resturl gives 500 internal error

Tags: alfresco

I am using

```
**GET /alfresco/service/api/path/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/children?types={types}&filter={filter?}&skipCount={skipCount?}&maxItems={maxItems?}**

**http://localhost:6060/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/4ae5fdf8-105e-4b87-bcda-b071a92785c1/children**
```

to get the children of User Homes folder

When i hit the above url i getting the following error. Please provide me an example which will retrieve all html contents inside User Homes folder. Thanks in advance.

```
The Web Script /alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/4ae5fdf8-105e-4b87-bcda-b071a92785c1/children has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:     An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    11040005 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 11043733 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js': 11043732

Exception:  java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter: Fri Aug 17 17:34:11 IST 2012

sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:256)
sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:570)
sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(BasicChecker.java:157)
sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:109)
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:117)
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:328)
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178)
java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250)
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:255)
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:243)
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:156)
sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1014)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:623)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:320)
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49)
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:367)
org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:78)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:65)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy13.query(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:146)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy13.query(Unknown Source)
org.alfresco.cmis.mapping.CMISServicesImpl.getChildren(CMISServicesImpl.java:570)
org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISScript.queryChildren(CMISScript.java:402)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3._c0(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js:134)
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js)
org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js)
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.exec(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js)
org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:483)
org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:191)
org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:282)
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1128)
org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISWebScript.executeScript(CMISWebScript.java:46)
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:393)
org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:462)
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:500)
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:316)
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:372)
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Exception:  java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException - timestamp check failed

sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:139)

Exception:  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException - PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed

sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)

Exception:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed

com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)

Exception:  org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException - 11043732

org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:366)

Exception:  org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 11043733 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js': 11043732

org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:195)

Exception:  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 11040005 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 11043733 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js': 11043732

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:905)

Server: Community v4.0.0 (b 3835) schema 5,019
Time:   Dec 4, 2012 10:57:32 AM

Diagnostics:    Inspect Web Script (org/alfresco/cmis/children.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two key bits in the exception that explain what's going on:Exception:

`Exception:  java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter: Fri Aug 17 17:34:11 IST 2012`

`org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:366)`

These tell us that you have configured Alfresco to talk to SOLR over SSL, and that the certificate that SOLR is responding with has expired. I'm guessing that you're using the default ones? If so, follow [advice like this](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=45940) or the sticky notice on the Alfresco support forums to resolve it. (You need to either upgrade, or drop in some newer certs). If you created the expired certificate yourself, you'll need to regenerate.

Actually, make that three problems the exception shows:

> org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c3.exec(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/children.get.js)

You're using the old CMIS URLs, you should switch to the new ones. See [cmis.alfresco.com](http://cmis.alfresco.com/) for details of the AtomPub or WebServices URLs that you should be using instead.

Comment: Now when i hit the url **http://localhost:6060/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/4ae5fdf8-105e-4b87-bcda-b071a92785c1/children** the browser shows a dialog box asking me to select the service. The available services list in the dialog box are Google reader, wordpress.com, feedly, xml tree, news factory. when i select the feedly it shows "failed to get feed information". Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Even the other service return the same.

Comment: Sounds like something is up with your browser. That URL returns an atompub document, which is xml based, you should be able to process it as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gagravarr. I came across the above stated problem in chrome. When I tried in safari the URL redirects to **feed:http://localhost:6060/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/4ae5fdf8-105e-4b87-bcda-b071a92785c1/children** and I get a warning message "safari can't open the page". When I tried in IE it ask me to subscribe feed for the first time. When I do that it displays the Folder name but its not showing the file names inside the folder. Same happens in FF. Please give your suggestion.

Comment: Stop using it direct in your browser! It's an api.... You can probably do "view source" to see the xml, but you need to write your code to use that!

Comment: I checked view source. And I checked it in restclient. But I am not getting the list of the children inside a folder. Can you please tell me how to check it. My alfresco is in local.